# how to export an object

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-class

couchbase.js:

```
import couchbase from 'couchbase';

const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://127.0.0.1');
const Bucket = cluster.openBucket();

export default Bucket
```

upsert.js:

```
import Bucket from './couchbase';
console.log(typeof Bucket);
Bucket.upsert(...)...
```

console.log Bucket value is undefined. How can I get the object exported in **es6**?

Comment: use `import { Bucket } from './couchbase';`

Comment: @ansh tried that, it says Bucket is not defined.

Comment: Try using a different name for the file instead of `couchbase` and `export default const Bucket = cluster.openBucket();` on the same line

Comment: rename the file seems to have make it work...

Comment: Your exports/imports look fine. Is it possible that `cluster.openBucket();` returns `undefined`? Make sure by also placing a `console.log(typeof Bucket);` in `couchbase.js`.

Comment: Is it a problem that the filename is the same as the node module `couchebase` ? Shouldn't the `./` part make sure that `Bucket` is imported from the local file instead from the node module?

Comment: Paths are relative, please double check if couchbase.js and upsert.js are on the same level (same folder/directory). Also, consider @Bergi's comment. The file name conflict shouldn't occur but that might depend on your transpiler and module bundler configuration.